# Whitespace on sliding the slider vue-carousel

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, carousel

I am working with vue-carousel version "vue3-carousel": "^0.2.6". When I slide the carousel, it adds white space to the left of the slide. How can I fix this issue?

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-clarke-llxgl6?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: provide working code link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-clarke-llxgl6?file=/src/App.vue